# how to do a shift/add multiplier in verilog?

Tags: verilog

I tried this

```
module sum(X,Y,Q);
  input [31:0] X,Y;
  output [31:0] Q;
  assign Q=X+Y;  
endmodule

module register(loadD, clk, rst, Q);
  input [31:0] loadD;
  input clk, rst;
  output reg [31:0] Q;
  always@(posedge clk, posedge rst) begin
    if(rst) begin
      Q<=0;
    end
    else if(clk) begin
      Q<=loadD;
    end
    else begin
      Q<=Q<<1;
    end  
  end

endmodule

module multiplier(A,B,andS,regS,clk,rst);
  input [31:0] A,B;
  input clk,rst;
  output [31:0] andS, regS;
  sum BL1(A,B,andS);
  register BL2(andS,clk,rst,regS);
  assign A=regS&{32{B[0]}};

endmodule
```

But don't work

Comment: What situation do you expect to lead to the shift operation happening in the register module?  Re-read your code and see if it will do what you expect.

Comment: Feels like homework to me. Do you know the shift, add, multiply algorithm? Because what is here is a far from what you need.

Comment: hm, I'll try fix the code. The simulation is not what I expect.. the code is just doing a sum.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a

```
posedge clk
```

in the sensitivity list of an always block, the condition

```
if(clk)
```

will be always true. And

```
else begin
  Q<=Q<<1;
end
```

will never be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

The logic in your `register` module seems incorrect. The sensitivity list you use requires a **rising** edge on either `clk` or `rst`, so **one or both of these will be high** when the module is activated. Now look at your `if...else if...else` logic and think about how you want that to work.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Elliot,
The problem appears in the lines

```
if(rst) begin
  Q<=0;
end
else if(clk) begin
  Q<=loadD;
end
else begin
  Q<=Q<<1;
end
```

If you are detecting both the clock and reset in the sensitivity list, then why you want to check again for a clock?
Read a similar answer here:  [Clock usage in the always block and in the event](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/511960/clock-usage-in-the-always-block-and-in-the-event)